# Find between custom tag if between tag has text or not

Tags: java, regex

in below code i can find any text between `<p|a|s>hello there</>` such as get `p|a|s` and `hello there` without any problem

```
   Pattern mftA_REGEX = Pattern.compile("<(.+?)>(.+?)</>");
   Matcher matcher = mftA_REGEX.matcher("<p|a|s>hello there</>");
   if (matcher.find()) {
       Log.e("tag ",matcher.group(1));
       Log.e("text ",matcher.group(2));
   }
```

now when i don't have `p|a|s` like with `<>hello there</>` matcher couldn't find. in my string `p|a|s` is optional, how can i change `Pattern.compile("<(.+?)>(.+?)</>");` to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optional `?` on the group should be outside the group, i.e. after `)`:

```
<(.+)?>
```

Or if you want to match the empty string, then:

```
<(.*)>
```

See working example on [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/yMt4D4/3)

Comment: it seems `(.*)` better than `(.+)?` because `(.*)` can be find correctly, whats your suggestion?

Comment: I see, depends whether you want no match, or match empty string.

Comment: @westom i want to match empty string

Comment: OK use `(.*)` then.